# Mysql sleep command is locking so much rows for long time

Tags: mysql, database

I was trying to update something in DB after imporitng dump but on commit I receive timeout, and on waiting and trying the same command after 1 hour it works.

After some anaylsis I watched running transaction using 
`show engine innodb status;`
and found there is transaction is locking some rows and going to be up like this:

*---TRANSACTION 14752, ACTIVE 1177 sec
36 lock struct(s), heap size 6544, 174 row lock(s), undo log entries 401
MySQL thread id 17, OS thread handle 0x7fdda87ee700, query id 150523 192.17.0.6 MyApp cleaning up*

on `show full processlist;`
I see this thread with id = 17 is *Sleep* command.

any Idea please?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A friend asked me to disable SQL strict mode  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html

`SET GLOBAL sql_mode = '';
SET SESSION sql_mode = '';`

This fixed concurrent query timeout issue.